# Change URL Of Overridden Templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

On my website `user`s access their accounts by going to the following address:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/users_area/username/profile
```

There they will find a button 'change password' (an overridden django template) which will take them to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/password/change/
```

It is very small and I'm probably being too picky but is it possible to keep this overridden template but change its url? I'd instead like the `change password` url to be something like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/users_area/username/password/change/
```

I've tried creating a template within my user's app, copying the 'change password' template content into there, then linking to it rather than to the overridden 'change password' template, but (obviously, in hindsight) it doesn't work.

---

I'll add as a side note. I actually have two user types, `users` and `powerusers`. Each has a unique and rather different 'users_area':

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/users_area/username/profile
```

and

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/powerusers_area/username/profile
```

If I get an answer to my above question I'm actually hoping to apply it to both of my different user types (shouldn't be hard but thought I should mention it).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this
urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    # other URLS
    path('/users_area/username/password/change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view, name='change_password'),
    # more URLS from auth?
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. The only problem is that submitting the form on this page refreshes the page to ```http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/password/change/```, I guess I'll need to override the view.py and redirect after form submission to```/users_area/username/password/change/```. Does that sound right?

Comment: If you go that far in customization, I think it's best to write our own password change view & template.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to customize them, even have a customized MyUser model, you can still re-use a lot from Django like this

```
    # authentication
    path('user_register', user_register_view, name='user_register'),
    path('login', login_view, name='login'),
    path('logout', logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('change_password', change_password_view, name='change_password'),
    path('reset_password/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="MyUser/password_reset.html"),
         name="reset_password"),
    path('reset_password_sent/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name="MyUser/password_reset_sent.html"),
         name="password_reset_done"),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="MyUser/password_reset_form.html"),
         name="password_reset_confirm"),
    path('reset_password_complete/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name="MyUser/password_reset_done.html"),
         name="password_reset_complete"),
    path('profile/<username>', profile_view, name='profile'),
```